Prove absolute value function using defining properties
When we are extending absolute value to complex number or learning norm, we are using the same properties of absolute value( Non-negativity, positive definite, multiplicativity and triangle inequality). But can we use these 4 properties to define the absolute value function itself?

It is usually called a norm, so look his up in wiki

no, i’m not talking about norm. I’m pretty sure these 4 properties can uniquely characterise the absolute value function. I am just wondering how to establish these properties to the standard definition of absolute value function

This question is similar to: Norms on the reals. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

why do you assume absolute value in R or C are not norms?
